# Does negative int number from exception indicates more than just a number?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, exception

Simple code indeed :

```
int number = int.MaxValue;
    number = number+1;
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Questions :

1) there's should be overflowException. there isn't. why is that?

2) Does the number `-2147483648` indicates something about :

- ) how many bytes is beyond limit size  ?
- ) if i see `-2147483648`  , How can I know ( if there wasnt an exception) - if this number came from exception ? - must I wrap it with Try Catch ?

p.s.  when i wrote :

```
int number = int.MinValue;
    number = number-1;
Console.WriteLine(--number);
```

I got  : `2147483647` (still no exception).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There's should be overflowException. there isn't. why is that?

By default, C# doesn't do overflow checking. You can enable it for a whole assembly (in the "Advanced" bit of the build tab in VS, or `/checked+` from the command line) or for a block/expression using the `checked` keyword

For the second part of your question, `-2147483648` is just `int.MinValue` - signed integers do that, rolling from a very large positive number to a very large negative number.

For example, if you use `sbyte` (the signed byte type):

```
sbyte number = 127; // sbyte.MaxValue
number++;
Console.WriteLine(number); // Prints -128
```

There's nothing funny going on here - it's just normal [2s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) overflow.

Or using `byte` (unsigned)

```
byte number = 255; // byte.MaxValue
number++;
Console.WriteLine(number); // Prints 0
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Was editing for that - no, it's not indicating an exception at all. It's just the result of the overflow.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Gah, sorry - byte is unsigned in C#. You'll need sbyte. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a `checked` block to get an exception. Arithmetic overflow is unchecked by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the number -2147483648 indicates something about:

It's the min value.  When you overflow you'll wrap, so `maxValue+1 == MinValue`, `MaxValue + 2 == MinValue + 1`, etc.
The same logic applies in the other direction; `MinValue - 1 == MaxValue`.

Answer (score 1):

int has a minimal value and a maximal value. If you are overflowing the max value, it simply cycles down to the minimal value.

Example:

int cant have numbers from -10 to 10.
int i = 8; // 8
i++; // 9
i++; // 10
i++; // -10
i++; // -9
i -= 2; // 10
i += 10; // -1

To get overflow exception, use a check block, since it is not checked by default.

```
checekd
{
    int i = int.MaxValue;
    i++; // throws
}
```